# C reference to library object

Tags: c++, c, ansi-c

Im working with my arduino to improve my C knowlege. I made several attemps, but I can't get it to work:-( 
I hope someone can help me.

I have different objects from a library.

```
Adafruit_NeoPixel hours = Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIXELS, .....);
Adafruit_NeoPixel minutes = Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIXELS, ....-);
Adafruit_NeoPixel seconds = Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIXELS, .....);
```

Now I want to call a function several times with a pointer to the declared library object (hours, minute & seconds => E.G POINTERTOLIB ?)

```
void showTime(int iShowTime, **POINTERTOLIB** ) 
{
    int ones = iShowTime % 24; 

    //set LEDs according to acutal Time
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) 
    {
        ((ones >> i) & 1) ? **POINTERTOLIB** .setPixelColor(i, **POINTERTOLIB** .Color(0,150,0)) :          **POINTERTOLIB** .setPixelColor(i, hours.Color(0,0,0));
        **POINTERTOLIB** .setBrightness(40);
    }
    **POINTERTOLIB** .show(); // This sends the updated pixel color to the hardware.
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your question is unclear, are you trying to pass pointers to all three objects?

Comment: You can use the following signature `void showTime(int iShowTime, Adafruit_NeoPixel *pObj)`. Inside `showTime` you can call the member_functions of `Adafruit_NeoPixel` by `pObj->setPixelColor()` `pObj->Color()`.  You can call `showTime` as follows `showTime(3, &hours);` or `showTime(3, &minutes);`

Comment: @sameerkn Can you add your comment as an answer to this question? According to the OP it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to call the function `showTime` several times using different objects (`hours, minutes, seconds`) of `class Adafruit_NeoPixel` then you can use the following signature:

```
void showTime(int iShowTime, Adafruit_NeoPixel *pObj);
```

Therefore, now `showTime` expects a pointer to any valid object of `class Adafruit_NeoPixel`.

Inside `showTime` you can call the member_functions of `class Adafruit_NeoPixel` as follows:

```
pObj->setPixelColor() 
pObj->Color().
```

You can call `showTime` as follows:

```
showTime(3, &hours); or showTime(3, &minutes);
showTime(3, &hours); or showTime(3, &hours);
showTime(3, &hours); or showTime(3, &seconds);
```